# Unable to open the Sqllite DB file when lancuhing the application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sqlite, setup-project

I used the PostBuildevnt script to launch the application form link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0&CommentPosted=true

and launching the app successfully.I am using the sqllite for app.
I added the DB file in Application Folder/DataBase and using the following code to open the Db file.

```
string ConnectionString = "data source=" + Path.GetFullPath(".") + "\\DataBase\\CATTDB.db";
```

If i launch the app from the installation wizard,it is not connecting to db file.it is throwing the error like **"Unable to open the file".**

If i launch from the start menu or desktop icon ,it is working fine..

What is the problem here?
please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the files are copying correctly..

I tried with `Application.ExecutablePath` instead of `Path.GetFullPath(".")`

it work's great...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your working directoy is different when started from the installer...

What does `Path.GetFullPath(".")` return in this case (log and/or display the value)?

There is always the issue of permission/rights - depending on your OS (i.e. Windows 7...) and the user your running the app with (i.a. Administrator?) for security reasons you are not allowed to write in the application directory... if you need someplace with read+write you should use http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath.aspx

Just check whether the db is in that path -if not copy it there- and use it there...

Other locations could be  ApplicationData/CommonApplicationData/LocalApplicationData from http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/14tx8hby.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx